# Меню Wayfinder подменю не выводится

Tags: modx, wayfinder

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`[[!UltimateParent?id=`[[*id]]`]]` &rowTpl=`rowTpl` &outerTpl=`outerTpl`]]
```

Выводит все меню главное, при указании id 
    [[!Wayfinder? &startId=`[[!UltimateParent?id=`[[*6]]`]]` &rowTpl=`rowTpl` &outerTpl=`outerTpl`]]
    В данный момент стоит 
    [[Wayfinder?&startId=`6`&level=`0`&outerTpl=`outerCat`&rowTpl=`innerowMenu`]]
    Не особо понимаю как сделать, чтобы выводило подменю

Comment: скрин структуры документов покажите + скрин полей документа(который должен выводиться в подменю)

Хотя я думаю,уже поздновато))

Answer (score 1):

К примеру

```
[[!Wayfinder? &startId=`0` &level=`1` &showSubDocCount=`true`]]
```

выведет ссылки всех ресурсов без дочерних ресурсов
Скорее всего вам нужно просто указать **level=`10`** например, чтобы вывод ссылок был с углублением на 10 дочерних ресурсов